# Spring Integration Sftp failed to upload but simple Jsch upload is ok. Why?

Tags: spring-integration, sftp, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

I use Spring Integration SFTP to upload files to a sftp server. When I send some concurrent requests or heavy files, I received Socket Clode exception.
But when I send directly the same file with simple Jsch client, even with concurrent calls, everything seems to be ok.

I use default config for both libraries. Spring SFTP uses Jsch, does it configure in such a way it could cause the error ? Is there a special configuration or operation made by Spring but not in the default configuration or behavior than simple Jsch ?

Comment: I just saw that isSharedSession=true in my spring integration sftp config. But false by default when using jsch directly.

Comment: Did it fix your problem? The `isSharedSession` is a `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` (therefore Spring) option. It has nothing to do with jsch client. Would be really great to see a difference in configuration for raw jsch and whatever you have for `DefaultSftpSessionFactory`...

Comment: @ArtemBilan, yes the problem is fixed. Sorry for my confusing previous comment. Not well written. When setting isSharedSession to true, Spring doesn't close the session, that remains in a pool in order to avoid close/reopen operations. It causes some "Socket Closed" errors with some sftp servers (depending of their config). When using raw jsch client with dedicated session + channel per operation its'ok, using isSharedSession=false is also ok, so in some way, isSharedSession = false could be seen as equivalent to raw jsch operation with open/close for each operation.

Comment: Got. Would you mind to explain of that as an answer to your own question? That will help the rest of community with similar problem in the future

Comment: @ArtemBilan, Copied my comment as an answer. But my remaining question is why did it fail ? Do you have an idea why some server, depending on their config, don't work correctly with a spring client configured with isSharedSession option setted to true ?

Comment: Or maybe that sometimes, Spring don't check (correctly) that the session is still open or can't reopen it before giving it the session pool client ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed. When setting isSharedSession to true, Spring doesn't close the session, that remains in a pool in order to avoid close/reopen operations. It causes some "Socket Closed" errors with some sftp servers (depending of their config). When using raw jsch client with dedicated session + channel per operation its'ok, using isSharedSession=false is also ok, so in some way, isSharedSession = false could be seen as equivalent to raw jsch operation with open/close for each operation

Comment: So, yeah... It is not recommended to use shared session for concurrent activity. In most cases we just need such a single session on the Inbound Channel Adapter, which in general is a single-threaded polling component: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound. For concurrent sends, it is better to let sessions to be spawned via `CachingSessionFactory` and reused respectively.

Comment: I'm already using CachingSessionFactory. When I use with shared session it fails. It's ok with isShareSession=false

Comment: But Spring docs sans that isSharedSession=true should be used with CachingsessionFactory, but it fails sometimes

Comment: I don't see that sentence, but still that probably is about reading in the inbound channel adapter anyway: not about writing in the outbound channel adapter, especially when it is concurrent and long-lived.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-session-caching

Comment: JSch supports multiple channels (operations) over a connection to the server. By default, the Spring Integration session factory uses a separate physical connection for each channel. Since Spring Integration 3.0, you can configure the session factory (using a boolean constructor arg - default false) to use a single connection to the server and create multiple JSch channels on that single connection.

When using this feature, you must wrap the session factory in a caching session factory, as described below, so that the connection is not physically closed when an operation completes.

Comment: Well, that's old doc: something has been changes since there. I don't recommend a caching for sending operations.

Comment: Several components (rabbit listeners, etc...) uses the sessionFactory, not only for uploaling. CachingSessionFactory allows to use a pool and limits its size. Is there a problem if I encapsulate DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false), that closes sessions after each use, in a CachingSessionFactory to control the size of the pool and distribute the sessions ? Or should I replace the CachingSessionFactory by something else to control the pool ?

Comment: Yes, that's OK: no sharing, but caching.

Answer (score 0):

Bean configuration that fixed the problem :

```
@Bean("speosSessionFactory")
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> speosSftpSessionFactory(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false);
    factory.setHost(applicationProperties.getHost());
    factory.setPort(applicationProperties.getPort());
    factory.setUser(applicationProperties.getUser());
    if (applicationProperties.getPrivateKey() != null) {
        factory.setPrivateKey(applicationProperties.getPrivateKey());
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(applicationProperties.getPrivateKeyPassphrase());
    } else {
        factory.setPassword(applicationProperties.getPassword());
    }
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory, applicationProperties.getMaxSessions());
}
```